# Error validating DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm trying to write a DTD for an XML file.Here it is : https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/courses-noID.xml

Here's my DTD

```
    <!ELEMENT Course_Catalog (Department*) >
<!ELEMENT Department (Title*, Chair*, Course*) >
<!ATTLIST Department Code CDATA #REQUIRED >
<!ELEMENT Title ANY >
<!ELEMENT Chair (Professor) >
<!ELEMENT Professor (First_Name, Middle_Initial?, Last_Name) >
<!ELEMENT First_Name ANY >
<!ELEMENT Last_Name ANY >
<!ELEMENT Course (Title, Description?, Instructors, Prerequisites?) >
<!ATTLIST Course Number CDATA #REQUIRED Enrollment CDATA #IMPLIED >
<!ELEMENT Description ANY >
<!ELEMENT Instructors (Professor*, Lecturer?) >
<!ELEMENT Lecturer (First_Name, Middle_Initial?, Last_Name) >
<!ELEMENT Middle_Initial ANY >
<!ELEMENT Prerequisites (Prereq*)>
<!ELEMENT Prereq ANY >
```

Well it looks almost fine but there is a slight error.It says 'validity error : Element Instructors content does not follow the DTD, expecting (Professor* , Lecturer?), got (Lecturer Professor Professor )'.Isn't * means any number of elements?Why is there an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't * means any number of elements?Why is there an error?

Yes, but the `,` is specifying an order. Your model `(Professor* , Lecturer?)` means zero or more `Professor` **followed by** zero or one `Lecturer`. The XML found an occurrence of one `Lecturer` followed by 2 `Professor`.

This model could be `(Lecturer,Professor+)`, but it depends on what the other `Instructors` elements look like. Start with `(Lecturer,Professor+)` and "loosen" it as required.

Comment: I tried yours as well but this time it gives another error because there is another (Professor, Lecturer) element.Is there any way to get rid of ordering?Also I looked for your e-mail but couldn't find it :)

Comment: @JohnRock - Yes, use `|` instead. Try this: `(Professor|Lecturer)+`

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have written your DTD first ... but ...

Why don't you download the trial version of Stylus Studio that includes a DTD generator.
http://www.stylusstudio.com/dtd%5Fgenerator.html